# How do I make the background image cover the entire background without the image repeating and the navigation link positioned at the top-right in line

Tags: html, css

```
body{
    display: flex;
    background: url("images/benzo.jpg") no-repeat center;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

This is the code sample where I inserted the background image

Answer (score 2):

`background-size: cover` is what you want to cover the entire page with your image:

```css
body{
display: flex;
background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png") no-repeat center;
height: 100vh;
color: #fff;
min-height: 500px;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Regarding your nav bar, I'm not entirely sure how you have your HTML set up, but you could do something along these lines. It's not pretty, so don't judge me lol.

Essentially, you could just put your `<a>` tags in a `div` and then set the `text-align` property for said `div` to `right`. See below:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png")
    no-repeat center;
  color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
div.nav{
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
div.links{
  text-align: right;
}
.a-color {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2vw;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-spacing: -2px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s;
}

.a-color:hover{
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="links">
  <a class="a-color">TEXT</a>
  <a class="a-color">TEXT</a>
  <a class="a-color">TEXT</a>
  <a class="a-color">TEXT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. The cover works fine though but what about the navigation links. This is what I have so far;. a-color{ color:#007bff; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; padding: 15px; overflow: hidden; word-spacing: -2px; letter-spacing: 4px; }